# AWS Lambda Layers - git push only .zip file but no nodejs folder

Tags: javascript, git, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codecommit

I'm trying to add a layer for my aws lambda function.

The layer folder is structured like this:

```
layers/
  nameOfLayer/
     --nameOfLayer.zip
     --nodejs/
       -- node_modules
       -- package-lock.json
       -- package.json
```

And the nameOfLayer.zip file is structured like this:

```
nameOfLayer.zip
 --nodejs/
   -- node_modules
   -- package-lock.json
   -- package.json
```

If I `git push` this to my repo, I can see the .zip file but not the nodejs folder.

My .gitignore file looks like this:

```
*.js
!jest.config.js
*.d.ts
!lambda/*.js
.vscode
!layers/*.json
node_modules
*.json

# CDK asset staging directory
.cdk.staging
cdk.out
```

Why is this happening and what is the solution?

Thanks in advance

EDIT_1: My repo is at CodeCommit. Are there more options to set up stuff than the .gitignore file?

Comment: What is showing `git status` ?

Comment: On branch XYZ
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/XYZ'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to replace `!layers/*.json` with `!layers/**.json`

The former would match `layers/file.json` but not `layers/subdir/file.json`

You need to use the double asterisk to match multiple subdirectories.

Refer to: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format

Comment: I've tried it out and in theory this makes total sense! Unfortunately it still doesn't upload it to my repo...

Answer (score 0):

I've added `!package.json` to the `.gitignore` probably not the best practice but it works